# Properly display a Rails flash error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am struggling to get the flash[:error] message to display properly on my browser but I get this instead[image]
I need it to display a "must exist" or "author must exist" error message. without the extra syntax and the brackets. I know it appears as a hash but I can't seem to fix this

This is what my create action looks like

```
@policy = Policy.create(policy_params)
  
      respond_to do |format|
        if @policy.valid?
         format.html { redirect_to policy_url(@policy), notice: "Policy was successfully created." }
         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @policy}
        else
          format.html do
            flash[:error] = @policy.errors
            redirect_to new_policy_path
         end
        end
```

while in my views the flash error syntax looks something like this

```
<%= flash[:error] %></h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `full_messages` property to make errors:
`flash[:error] = @policy.errors.full_messages.first`
or
`flash[:error] = @policy.errors.full_messages.to_sentence`

Also it's better to use `alert` or `notice`
https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/11/rails-flash-messages/

Comment: Why is it better?

Comment: Is there a way to display and iterate these errors in the views and not in the controller?

Comment: @morrismenanya you need to use <%= flash[:notice] %> where you need

Comment: ok. i figured it already. I used the flash[:notice] to alert the user for a successful process while I chose to use flash[:error] for a failed process. That way I can style both notifications uniquely, thanks anys, I worked around your initial solution and it helped